# How to make dense matrix as input to Tfidf transformer?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, tf-idf

Basically, how to make this code running with my data?

```
    # build term document matrix
    V = len(word2idx)
    N = len(sentences)  #sentences=sents
    print("V:", V, "N:", N)

    # create raw counts first
    A = np.zeros((V, N))    

    j = 0
    for sentence in sentences:
        for i in sentence:
            A[i,j] += 1
        j += 1
    print("finished getting raw counts")

    transformer = TfidfTransformer()
    A = transformer.fit_transform(A.T).T
```

The problem is those values of V or N are consec. 200k+ and 30k. There are far too beyond my memory stack and @ the line `np.zeros(` the memory occurs. Can I avoid this loop and produce `A` matrix dense as a input to the Tfidf Straightforwardly?

I've read I must use PySpark. Should I really?

Comment: Have you tried [reducing the dimensionality](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/lsimodel.html) of the word2idx?

Comment: No, but I can try it now. Thanks for suggestion.